# Functions differentiable on a closed contour

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is differentiable on a closed contour in $\mathbb{C}$, is it bounded on the contour? I guess if we take a closed path $\gamma(t),a\leqslant t\leqslant b$ wher $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$, then if I take $M=\sup\{f(\gamma(t))\mid a\leqslant t\leqslant b\}$, then $f(z)\leqslant M$ on this contour. Is it a proper proof?

Comment: is the contour simple?

Comment: Yes it is. In fact I made a mistake above that I should have put modulus $|f(\gamma(t))|$

Comment: I am not sure how happy you will be with this answer, or if it is an answer so i'll post it in the comments. I'd like feedback from anyone else that sees it. Since $f(z)$ is differentiable on the closed contour it is continuous. Since we are talking about a simple closed contour, this set is compact. Since $f$ is continuous and $\gamma (t)$ compact, $f(\gamma(t))$ is compact and therefore bounded.

Comment: That's exactly what I was planning to say, Eoin. So we're either both right or both wrong.